# How to dynamically type text in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I want to enter dynamic text in cypress, so at each run, the name field will not have repeated input, for example name1, name 2...

So in the js file I would have something like

```
And("I enter a name", () => {
     portalPage.roleName().type("Cypress admin" + 1, { force: true })
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeking random inputs, then lodash `.random()` will generate a random number from 0 to the input.

```js
// will generate random number between 0 and 9999
portalPage.roleName().type(`Cypress admin${Cypress._.random(9999)}`, { force: true })
```

Answer (score 3):

Between runs you have to write the last used number to a fixture,

```js
And("I enter a name", () => {
  cy.fixture('name-num.json').then(num => 
     const next = num +1;
     portalPage.roleName().type(`Cypress admin ${next}`, { force: true })
     cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/name-num.json', next.toString())
})
```

If you do this multiple times in the same run, `cy.fixture` won't work because it caches the value it reads.

Instead use `readFile()`

```js
And("I enter a name", () => {
  cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/name-num.json').then(num => 
     const next = num +1;
     portalPage.roleName().type(`Cypress admin ${next}`, { force: true })
     cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/name-num.json', next.toString())
})
```

Comment: I used the first option but I get:: next is not defined

Comment: Sorry I missed out `const`

Answer (score 0):

If you only needed the values to be different within the same spec, you could store the value in a Cypress environment variable. The environment variable will not be cleared until the spec has finished running.

```js
And("I enter a name", () => {
     // set the environment variable to current value + 1, or if it hasn't been set, 1.
     Cypress.env("myNumber", Cypress.env("myNumber")++ ?? 1);
     // use the environment variable
     portalPage.roleName().type("Cypress admin" + Cypress.env("myNumber"), { force: true });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [faker js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker) for generating unique names and then using it. To install use `npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev`. And your test should look like:

```js
const faker = require('faker')

And('I enter a name', () => {
  Cypress.env('Name', faker.name.firstName())
  portalPage
    .roleName()
    .type('Cypress admin ' + Cypress.env('Name'), {force: true})
})
```

If you want you can just use the full name as well instead of `Cypress admin some-name`.

```js
const faker = require('faker')

And('I enter a name', () => {
  Cypress.env('Name', faker.name.findName())
  portalPage
    .roleName()
    .type(Cypress.env('Name'), {force: true})
})
```